# Adjusting the size of div containing text

Tags: html, css

See an example here. http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/1/  (look at the last image)

I am trying to add text over the image and but with my method if the number of lines exceed the height of the containing div the text overflows.Is there a way to adjust the size of the div in accordance to the number of lines.

```
<div class="relatedposts">
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="img1" >
        <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="img2" >
         <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
  </div>
</div>


 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   }
  .relatedposts {
  display:table; 
  width:1024px;font-size: 0;
  /* fix inline gap */
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .relatedthumb {
  float: left;
  margin-left:5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
 .relatedthumb img {
  text-align:center;
  }
 .justin-cover {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 500;
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

Comment: If you remove `.justin-cover { height: 30%; }` it works just like you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/2/

Comment: Change height to auto on .justin-cover

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
.justin-cover {
    ...
    height: 30%;
    ...
}
```

To this

```
.justin-cover {
    ...
    min-height: 30%;
    max-height: 100%; // Add this one too
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable, you could set overflow property.
    overflow:auto;